# Solution to this error

Tags: sql

I have written this query:

```
String sql = "Update db " +                         
"SET LName = '"+txtLName.getText()+"'," +                               
"ATC_Code = '"+txtATCcode.getText()+"'," +                              
"ATC_Name= '"+txtATCname.getText()+"'," +                               
"Course_Name =  '"+txtCourseName.getText()+"'," +
"Course_Fee = '"+txtCourseFee.getText()+"'," +
"Where FName = '"+txtFName.getText()+"' ";
```

And I got an error like:

```
Malformed SQL Statement: Expected ',', found 'Anuja'`.
Statement:Update db SET LName = 'df',ATC_Code = '323',ATC_Name= 'sd',Course_Name =  'd',Course_Fee = '534',Where FName = 'Anuja'
```

Comment: Can't you show us just the SQL statement? (Much easier to find the problem that way!)

Comment: Please `edit` your `question` title to some `meaningful` title

Answer (score 1):

Remove last `,` for `Set` statement:

```
String sql = "Update db " +
   "SET LName = '"+txtLName.getText()+"'," +
   "ATC_Code = '"+txtATCcode.getText()+"'," +
   "ATC_Name= '"+txtATCname.getText()+"'," +
   "Course_Name =  '"+txtCourseName.getText()+"'," +
   "Course_Fee = '"+txtCourseFee.getText() + //here does not need '
   "Where FName = '"+txtFName.getText()+"' ";
```

On a side note, this kind of sql command generation(concatenating strings that contains some values) are suspect to SQL injection attacks, to prevent this type of attacks, use paramaters and set the parameters values instead. See [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update db 
SET LName = 'df',
    ATC_Code = '323',
    ATC_Name= 'sd',
    Course_Name =  'd',
    Course_Fee = '534',
Where FName = 'Anuja'
```

Only will change remove last comma ','

```
Update db 
SET LName = 'df',
    ATC_Code = '323',
    ATC_Name= 'sd',
    Course_Name =  'd',
    Course_Fee = '534'
Where FName = 'Anuja'
```